# Does an Aegis' Climb astral suit customization function like Spider Climb?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

Does an [Aegis'](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/) [Climb](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits/) astral suit customization function like Spider Climb?

Comment: Is there something specific you're looking for here? Some aspect(s) of *spider climb* that you think Aegis' Climb would or might not inherit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not really

Aegis [Climb](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits/#Climb) does not reference Spider Climb and therefore does not 'function like' it.

### But mostly yes

[Spider Climb](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spider-climb/) does very little that a [Climb Speed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Climb) does not.

- +8 to Climb checks (both)
- Can Take 10 on Climb checks (both)
- Retain Dex to AC while Climbing (both)
- Cannot use the Run Action (both)
- Requires the [use of both hands](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/climb) (both)
- Can Climb across surfaces such as ceilings without handholds (Spider Climb)

Essentially, Aegis still need something to grab on to, but the option allows them to move more quickly and without sacrificing Dex to AC (protecting them from rogue ambushes and the like).